# getters and setters for array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to create getters and setters for these array of objects? I also have two methods to add these ships to the array of objects. One of them looks like. Is this the write way?

```
`public class College
{
  private Student[] student;
  private Teacher[] teacher;
  int count;
  public College()
  {
    student = new Student[9];
    teacher = new Teacher[9];
    count = 0;
  }

  public Student[] getStudent()
  {
    return student;
  }



  public void setStudent(Student[] student)
  {
    this.student = student;
  }
```

Comment: Why use hard-coded arrays with compile-time lengths? Maybe consider dynamic collections such as `ArrayList`, and then simply return an iterable `List` collection to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you would do it just like any other getter/setter, only difference is the return type and the parameters.

```
public SubmarineClass[] getSubmarine() {
    return submarine;
}

public void setSubmarine(SubmarineClass[] submarine) {
    this.submarine = submarine;
}

public FighterJetClass[] getFighterJet() {
    return fighterJet;
}

public void setFighterJet(FighterJetClass[] fighterJet) {
    this.fighterJet = fighterJet;
}
```

Comment: How will they be used in the main method then?

Comment: @chimmy102 If you had a ShipStorageObject named 'myObj' for example, you could do ```myObj.getSubmarine();``` and similarly for setting you could do ```myObj.setFighterJet(arg);```